# Using Multiprocessing to speed up the load of pandas while chunking large csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to read a csv file containing 7 million rows, and 10 columns. My hardware specifications are as follows:

[image: ![enter image description here]

My strategy is to load the datasets in terms of chunks:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize = 1000000, low_memory=False)
```

unfortunately, I am receiving this error that says:

```
bash:fork:Cannot allocate memory
```

which clearly tells me that something is wrong with the memory usage.
So I decided to load the dataframe using multiprocessing:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def read_csv(filename):
        return pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize = 1000000, low_memory=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = Pool(processes = 6)
        df_list = pool.map(read_csv, 'm_datasets.csv.gz')
```

but I am receiving an error:

```
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'm' does not exist: b'm'
```

rerunning the scripts it shows the same error but different letter:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'a' does not exist
```

What seems to be wrong here?

---

I have solved the above problem by using apply_async:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = Pool(processes = 6)
        df_list = pool.apply_async(read_csv,'m_datasets.csv.gz')
        for i in df_list:
                res = i.get()
```

however I have a new problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "eda.py", line 15, in <module>
        for i in df_list:
    TypeError: 'ApplyResult' object is not iterable
```

but when I use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        jobs = []
        pool = Pool(5)
        lists = pool.apply_async(file_reader, ['m_datasets.csv.gz'])
        for i in lists.get():
                print(i)
```

I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eda.py", line 12, in <module>
    for i in lists.get():
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x7f2417ebf748>'. Reason: 'AttributeError("Can't pickle local object '_make_date_converter.<locals>.converter'",)'
```

Comment: Images of text are generally problematic and unwelcome here.

Comment: What is the precise traceback when you get this error? The code you have shown here does not seem sufficient to repro.

Comment: Why do you think `multiprocessing` should help? If anything, it gives each process *less* memory.

Comment: The immediate fix is to put the file name in a list; but as discussed above, this code probably doesn't offer any efficiency gains.

Comment: @tripleee, thank you for the comment, and my apologies for the very messy post. While there are the existence of other efficient libraries (ie. Modin, Dask) or even using PySpark. This question is based on my curiosity if coupling chunking and multiprocessing will work. But basing on your comment, I guess my hypothesis is not valid.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and I have wondered about it myself. With RAM and CPU cores to spare, why *wouldn't* it be a good idea to parallelize the import? 
 (but then again, I'm not a computer scientist)